# Saving multiple matplotlib figures with multiprocessing using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocess

I try to use multiprocess to plot and save many figures.
Using code in [Saving multiple matplotlib figures with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866070/saving-multiple-matplotlib-figures-with-multiprocessing), I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

It works if I use the following code with library import inside the function and with the multiprocess fork of multiprocessing:

```py
# taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866070/saving-multiple-matplotlib-figures-with-multiprocessing

from multiprocess import Pool

def do_plot(number):
    import numpy.random as random
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    fig = plt.figure(number)

    a = random.sample(1000)
    b = random.sample(1000)

    # generate random data
    plt.scatter(a, b)

    plt.savefig("%03d.jpg" % (number,))
    plt.close()

    print("Done ", number)

pool = Pool(4)
pool.map(do_plot, range(4))
```

However, my real function depends on a big dataframe defined outside of it:

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3]})

def do_plot(number):
    import numpy.random as random
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    fig = plt.figure(number)

    a = df['A']
    b = df['B']

    # generate random data
    plt.scatter(a, b)

    plt.savefig("%03d.jpg" % (number,))
    plt.close()

    print("Done ", number)

pool = Pool(4)
pool.map(do_plot, range(4))
```

which returns:

```
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

What should I do to use a dataframe and other objects defined outside the `do_plot` function ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In `matplotlib` saving figures in multiprocessing doesn't work instead saving the full figure works. Here is a solution below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

def do_plot(ax):
    a = random.sample(range(1000),100)
    b = random.sample(range(1000),100)

    ax.scatter(a, b)

plots = 4
fig, ax = plt.subplots(plots)
pool = Pool(plots)
pool.map(do_plot, ax)
fig.savefig('full_figure.png')
```

Output:

[image: multiprocessing_matplotlib_plot]